# Why Google use HTML Fragment identifier (#) in search?

Tags: html, security, query-string

I noted that Google use HTML Fragment identifier in search engine, for example:

https://www.google.com/?#newwindow=1&safe=active&q=https://stackoverflow.com/

Is that for security reason? dose it improve security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably nothing to do with security.

The reason to pass something as a fragment in a URL is that if it never has to be sent to the server and should be interpreted on the client-side only for functional reasons, for example in JavaScript for building AJAX requests.

Comment: I think this related to traffic monitoring, an attacker can see what user searched for! or SSL can also encrypt the URL?

Comment: Nothing to do with traffic monitoring and security as said because [TLS/SSL encrypts the URL](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/4388/8340).

Answer (score 1):

> Is that for security reason? dose it improve security?

No and no.

It's just that they have made their search engine massively ajaxy and don't follow the best practice of `pushState` with a server side fallback position.